# How to add new Obect inside List<EntityClass>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am fetching the record from the database. I want to modify new record with the existing record.

I fetching last 6 months data, I want to modify my result ? If any months records I am not getting from the database.

How I can modify existing result List ?

```
public List<EntityClassName> fetchByType() throws CustomExpection{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        List<EntityClassName> result;
    
        try {
            
            result = (List<EntityClassName>) genDao.find(Query.byTpe, CommonUtil.getStartEndDate(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper(EntityClassName.class));
            result.forEach(
                userData -> {
                    String type = userData.getType_name();
                    log.info("Type:"+type);
                    //userData.setType_name(userData.getType_name()+" PPP");
                }
            );
            log.info("Size:"+result.size());
            
            System.err.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          log.error(
              "Something went wrong !!!",
              e.getMessage());
          throw new CustomExpection("Something went wrong !!!");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> sBarang = new ArrayList<Item>();
Item mItem = new Item(); // <-- instantiate a new Item.
mItem.setCode("101");
mItem.setName("Hammer");
mItem.setQty(10);
sBarang.add(mItem); // <-- add it to your List<Item>.
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32354167)

Comment: @Filburt: This appears to be an answer to me, based on the inline comments, though it'd certainly benefit from additional explanation.